# Mongoose lambda example creates a new connection everytime it gets triggered

Tags: mongoose, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, nestjs

I've been following the official mongoose documentation and have built the mongoose connection into my handler:

This is in the root of my handler file.

```js
let conn = null;
const uri = process.env.ORDERS_URI;

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  Logger.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + uri);
});
```

Now inside my actual handler function :

```js
export const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  if (conn == null) {
    console.log('CONN IS NULL');
    conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, {
      bufferCommands: false, // Disable mongoose buffering
      bufferMaxEntries: 0, // and MongoDB driver buffering
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
  }

  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  cachedServer = await bootstrapServer();
  return proxy(cachedServer, event, context, 'PROMISE').promise;
};
```

However, upon testing with serverless offline, for every hit I start a new connection.

Hit 1: 1 New 'connected to mongoose' message
Hit 2: 2 New 'connected to mongoose' message ...

and so on...

I've tried moving them around with a few variations but whichever way I still end up with the same 'bug'.

If I try to use `mongoose.createConnection` instead -- actually connecting to the DB will not work at all anywhere I put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because serverless offline performs require cache invalidation at each invocation. This is not the case on AWS Lambda. You can disable this behavior with `--skipCacheInvalidation` but it seems to [be gone anyway](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/commit/5ca569f14782edcecb4c97240f4c6e3bc148e1b1).